# How to pass parameter using Post method in mobilefirst 8.0 for javascript API to upload image on server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, post, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to send the image to the back end via post method because get method cannot support the long uri. I dont know how to pass parameter to adapter. I succeed to pass parameter using mfp7.1 mobile first but for mobilefirst 8.0 i need to use different method which is post method. Can someone explain to me

```
    var invocationData = {
    LOCALE: locale,
    CHANNEL: channel,
    CLIENT_OS: os,
    TYPE: type,
    ISSUE_TYPE: issueType,
    STATION: type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY' ? '' : station,
    CATEGORY: type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY' ? station : '',
    DESCRIPTION: desc,
    LOCATION: loc,
    CONTRACT_ACC_NO: accNo,
    PHOTOS: photo
  };

  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    '/adapters/Report/makeReport',
    WLResourceRequest.POST
  );
 request.sendFormParameters(invocationData).then(
function(response) {
    // success flow
},
function(error) {
    // fail flow
}
);
```

Javascript adapter

```
function invokeBackend(args, proc){
WL.Logger.info("Invoking Backend procedure " + proc);
WL.Logger.info(args);

var path = "SEB-Middleware/api/" + proc;
var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path,
        body : {
            contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            content: JSON.stringify(args)
        }
    };

var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
if(response &&
        (response['isSuccessful'] && response.isSuccessful) && 
        (response['statusCode'] && response.statusCode == 200)){
    return response;
}else{
    WL.Logger.warn("Invocation Error: " + proc);
    var locale = 'en';
    if(args && args['LOCALE']) locale = args.LOCALE;

    var resp = null;
    if(response['statusCode']){
        resp =  com.seb.mfp.utility.ResponseUtil.getErrorResponse(response.statusCode, locale);
    }else{
        resp = com.seb.mfp.utility.ResponseUtil.getErrorResponse(locale);
    }

    WL.Logger.warn(resp);

    return resp;
}
 }
```

I received  Cannot read property 'sendFormParameters' of undefined from console. How to pass parameter using my current json

Comment: More than client side, how is your adapter code written? Post details of the adapter method and how its arguments are structured.

Comment: i edit and add the source code on my adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention the error message is :

```
Cannot read property 'sendFormParameters' of undefined
```

I see this in your code:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    '/adapters/Report/makeReport',
    WLResourceRequest.POST
  );
 request.sendFormParameters(invocationData).then(
```

This needs to be corrected to:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    '/adapters/Report/makeReport',
    WLResourceRequest.POST
  );
 resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(invocationData).then(
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction,now  i face new error, the invocation json need to be in simple type. My invocation data already in json format based what i can see.